# Scripts for Selenium Chrome and htmlUnit

Tags: selenium, browser-automation

I have some Java scripts for Chrome browser and now I want to run the scripts in `htmlUnit`. I think the scripts are the same for both, but I got some error when running in htmlUnit? why? So basically which actions (`click()`?  `isDisplayed()`? etc.) only in Browser test but not in headless tests? and general documents about this difference? Thanks

#########   Seems css may have problem here but work OK in Chrome ##############

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Returned node was not an HTML element For documentation on this error,
>   please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05
>   22:01:35' System info: host: 'FGS-CIT-2758', ip: '192.168.200.201',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_40' Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByCssSelector(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1002)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:426)    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1648)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$5.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1302)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1644)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:550)
>     at com.ATIP400Suite.CH_ATIP40.mainCheck(CH_ATIP40.java:461)     at
>   com.ATIP400Suite.CH_ATIP40.main(CH_ATIP40.java:58)
>
> Line461 =
>   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.icon-meter.enlargeIcon")).isDisplayed()

Comment: also seems problem with Select() -  - Select period = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"))); period.getFirstSelectedOption().getText()

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then consider revising your question so that people have enough information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable javascript in `HtmlUnitDriver`?
If yes, before click check [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html):

1. `presenceOfElementLocated` (if you are not sure that an element is present on the DOM)
2. `elementToBeClickable`

good luck...